# TextView won't change when it is supposed to change?

Tags: java, android

I have this code that should add 1 point to the scoreTextView everytime a ball passes through a gap in a rectangle. My method .getTheRight gets the right of the rectangle. Here is my code:

```
public void onResume() //app moved to foreground (also occurs at app startup)
{
    final TextView scoreTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTextView);

    final int[] blackRectangleTopHeights = {0, (mScrHeight/10) * 1, (mScrHeight/10) * 2,(mScrHeight/10) * 3,
                                               (mScrHeight/10) * 4,(mScrHeight/10) * 5,(mScrHeight/10) * 6,
                                               (mScrHeight/10) * 7};

    final int[] blackRectangleBottomHeights = {(mScrHeight/10) * 3,(mScrHeight/10) * 4,(mScrHeight/10) * 5,
                                              (mScrHeight/10) * 6, (mScrHeight/10) * 7,(mScrHeight/10) * 8,
                                              (mScrHeight/10) * 9,mScrHeight};
    final Random randomGenerator = new Random();


    runCircle();

    //************Set up rectangle moving mechanism and Logic*********************

    mTmr2 = new Timer();
    mTsk2 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(blackRectangleTopHeights.length);
            int topBlackRectHeight = blackRectangleTopHeights[randomNumber];
            int bottomBlackRectHeight = blackRectangleBottomHeights[randomNumber];

            int rectWhite1Left = rectWhite1.getTheLeft() - mRectSpeed;
            int rectWhite1Right = rectWhite1.getTheRight() - mRectSpeed;
            rectWhite1.setX(rectWhite1Left, rectWhite1Right);

            int rectBlack1Left = rectBlack1.getTheLeft() - mRectSpeed;
            int rectBlack1Right = rectBlack1.getTheRight() - mRectSpeed;
            rectBlack1.setX(rectBlack1Left, rectBlack1Right);

            int rectWhite2Left = rectWhite2.getTheLeft() - mRectSpeed;
            int rectWhite2Right = rectWhite2.getTheRight() - mRectSpeed;
            rectWhite2.setX(rectWhite2Left, rectWhite2Right);

            int rectBlack2Left = rectBlack2.getTheLeft() - mRectSpeed;
            int rectBlack2Right = rectBlack2.getTheRight() - mRectSpeed;
            rectBlack2.setX(rectBlack2Left, rectBlack2Right);

            int rectWhite3Left = rectWhite3.getTheLeft() - mRectSpeed;
            int rectWhite3Right = rectWhite3.getTheRight() - mRectSpeed;
            rectWhite3.setX(rectWhite3Left, rectWhite3Right);

            int rectBlack3Left = rectBlack3.getTheLeft() - mRectSpeed;
            int rectBlack3Right = rectBlack3.getTheRight() - mRectSpeed;
            rectBlack3.setX(rectBlack3Left, rectBlack3Right);

            //Cycles rectangles and randomizes where middle rectangle will be postitoned vertically
            if (rectWhite1.getTheRight() > 0 && rectWhite1.getTheRight() < 10) {
                rectWhite1.setX(mScrWidth, rectWhite1.getRectWidth() + mScrWidth);
            }

            if (rectBlack1.getTheRight() > 0 && rectBlack1.getTheRight() < 10) {
                rectBlack1.setX(mScrWidth, rectBlack1.getRectWidth() + mScrWidth);
                rectBlack1.setY(topBlackRectHeight, bottomBlackRectHeight);
            }

            if (rectWhite2.getTheRight() > 0 && rectWhite2.getTheRight() < 10) {
                rectWhite2.setX(mScrWidth, rectWhite2.getRectWidth() + mScrWidth);
            }

            if (rectBlack2.getTheRight() > 0 && rectBlack2.getTheRight() < 10) {
                rectBlack2.setX(mScrWidth, rectBlack2.getRectWidth() + mScrWidth);
                rectBlack2.setY(topBlackRectHeight, bottomBlackRectHeight);
            }

            if (rectWhite3.getTheRight() > 0 && rectWhite3.getTheRight() < 10) {
                rectWhite3.setX(mScrWidth, rectWhite3.getRectWidth() + mScrWidth);
            }

            if (rectBlack3.getTheRight() > 0 && rectBlack3.getTheRight() < 10) {
                rectBlack3.setX(mScrWidth, rectBlack3.getRectWidth() + mScrWidth);
                rectBlack3.setY(topBlackRectHeight, bottomBlackRectHeight);
            }

            //Keeps track of score
            if (rectWhite1.getTheRight() == Math.round(mBallPos.x)) {

                mScoreboard.addPoint();
                scoreTextView.setText(mScoreboard.getScore() + "");
                Log.d(TAG, "If statement has been run!!!");
            }

            if (rectWhite2.getTheRight() == Math.round(mBallPos.x)) {

                mScoreboard.addPoint();
                scoreTextView.setText(mScoreboard.getScore() + "");
                Log.d(TAG, "If statement has been run!!!");
            }

            if (rectWhite3.getTheRight() == Math.round(mBallPos.x)) {

                // Update TextView here
                mScoreboard.addPoint();
                scoreTextView.setText(mScoreboard.getScore() + "");
                Log.d(TAG, "If statement has been run!!!");
            }



            RedrawHandler2.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    rectWhite1.invalidate();
                    rectWhite2.invalidate();
                    rectWhite3.invalidate();
                    rectBlack1.invalidate();
                    rectBlack2.invalidate();
                    rectBlack3.invalidate();

                }
            });



        }
    };
    mTmr2.schedule(mTsk2, 10, 10); //start timer (Timer 2)


    super.onResume();
} // onResume
```

Instead, no TextView update happens and the score stays the same. I don't understand why it won't update everytime the ball's x position equals the x position of the right point of the rectangle to be passed.

Comment: Probably because you don't get in the if statements. Have you tried to Log.d inside the if statements? Try to Log.d your mBallPos.x and getTheRight() for rectWhite1, rectWhite2, rectWhite3 to see their values.

Comment: I agree with @Carnal it's probably because you don't enter your if statements. Check to see if you actually go in.

Comment: @Grimbode  I just logged the code and you are right the if statements are not entered by my code. How do I fix this problem? Is it the if statement that is too exact for the device to process it or should I create a separate timer for this?

Comment: @Carnal I changed my code and now my app crashes whenever I reach the point where ball pos.x equals the rectangle's right value. What is going wrong?

Comment: At what line does it crash and what Exception is thrown? You can check this in Logcat.

Comment: @Carnal I used the log cat and realized I hadn't initialized mScoreboard. I fixed that and now it works. Thank you!!!